# Регулярно выражение в котором неважна последовательность

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Подскажите как написать регулярное выражение чтобы оно вмещало несколько умов, например ("[a-z]+[0-9]+"), при этом чтобы не была важна последовательность. Чтобы находило  "123qwer" и "qwer123"?

Comment: `[a-z0-9]+` не подходит?

Comment: Только не говорите, что вы валидируете пароли регулярками.  Там же простейший цикл.

Comment: @Ainar-G, да вы угадали думал это будет не тяжело). Не подскажите как можно проще это сделать?

Comment: @VladLukiuanchuk  См. ответ.

Comment: и да, где планируете применять?

Answer (score 1):

В комментарии вы не сказали, на каком языке вам нужна валидация
пароля :-) Вот код на паскале (почему бы и нет?), переписать на
любой другой язык — элеменарно:

```pascal
FUNCTION Valid(password: TPassword): Boolean;
VAR
    hasBigLetter: Boolean = False;
    hasSmallLetter: Boolean = False;
    hasNumber: Boolean = False;
    i: Integer;
BEGIN
    IF Length(password) < MinLen THEN
    BEGIN
        Valid := False;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        FOR i := 1 TO Length(password) DO
        BEGIN
            IF password[i] IN ['A' .. 'Z'] THEN
            BEGIN
                hasBigLetter := True
            END
            ELSE IF password[i] IN ['a' .. 'z'] THEN
            BEGIN
                hasSmallLetter := True
            END
            ELSE IF password[i] IN ['0' .. '9'] THEN
            BEGIN
                hasNumber := True
            END;
        END;

        Valid := hasBigLetter AND hasSmallLetter AND hasNumber;
    END;
END;
```

Comment: а прикольно.. можно добавить поиск во входящей строке имя пользователя и наиболее часто встречающихся паролей.

Answer (score 1):

ну, например с помощью Positive Lookahead (?=.*\d):

```
/(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[\da-zA-Z]{8,}/
```

пароль должен содержать 8 символов, минимум одну строчную и одну заглавную латинские буквы и одну цифру.

[просмотреть](https://regex101.com/r/dRLpRu/1)

Comment: Я когда вижу такие формы, которые пренебрегают преждевременно, я сразу их закрываю. Это пользователя выбор, какой хочет пароль, пусть тот и использует. также не понимаю тех. кто пытается через регулярки валидировать `@email`.

Comment: @And: Ваше право, но.. Существуют различные порталы, на которых необходимо регистрироваться пользователям, далеким от Ваших Интернетов. Так вот им НЕОБХОДИМО указать, что пароль 111 или qwerty недостаточно хорош. Иначе они придут назавтра со слезами и будут вопрошать: ну ты же доктор! почему не предотвратил?